# Create New Passport Client for a User in Laravel and Passport inside Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport, laravel-7

Is there a way to create passport client in Laravel. For example, to create a Token, we can do:

```
$user = $request->user();
$token = $user->createToken("myApp")->accessToken;
```

Do we something for Client too?

```
$user = $request->user();
$token = $user->createClient("myApp")->accessClient;
```

I checked the documentation and it is possible to create a client using an API, but the example is in Vue.JS

```
const data = {
    name: 'Client Name',
    redirect: 'http://example.com/callback'
};

axios.post('/oauth/clients', data)
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
})
.catch (response => {
    // List errors on response...
});
```

But I am unable to run this example in POSTMAN... I am not sure which function or method is being triggered for above API Call. How can I make use of this POST method outside VueJS.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I've tried to recreate the Vue code using Guzzle in the controller, but for some reason it's not working. At all. How hard can it be? What am I not seeing?